# Query with date Pivot and date order

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have this simple table and query:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MwdP08WWmkG13fGmKjB5hpL-D_uqgAu0lsXrO8WcE1M

the problem is, I cannot get the columns to be ordered by date. I've tried transpose+sort+transpose, but it doesn't work as it puts "2019-10-1" before "2019-9-1" (because it interprets date as text). Is there any way to get this sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(A:D; 
 "select B,sum(C),sum(D) 
  where B is not null 
  group by B 
  pivot A"); 
 "select Col1,"&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; 
  {"Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)+1))\ 
   "Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("A"&2+COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)&":A"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)*2+1))})))
```

[image: 0]

and if you want to remove that sum:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY(QUERY(A:D; 
 "select B,sum(C),sum(D) 
  where B is not null 
  group by B 
  pivot A "); 
 "select Col1,"&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; 
  {"Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)+1))\ 
   "Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("A"&2+COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)&":A"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)*2+1))})));
  " sum "; " "))
```

[image: 0]

---

> where can I add a date filter `where A >= date '2019-07-01'`. I've tried adding it in the first block, but I keep getting the error: `"Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: ColXX"`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY(QUERY(A:D; 
 "select B,sum(C),sum(D) 
  where B is not null 
    and A >= date '2019-7-1'
  group by B 
  pivot A "); 
 "select Col1,"&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; 
  {"Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ">="&DATE(2019;7;1))+1))\ 
   "Col"&ROW(INDIRECT("A"&2 +COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ">="&DATE(2019;7;1))&":A"&
                             COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A2:A; A2:A; ">="&DATE(2019;7;1))*2+1))})));
  " sum "; " "))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I was hoping for some less MacGyver-style solution but I'll take it :D Thanx.

Comment: BTW, where can I add a date filter " where A >= date '2019-07-01' ". I've tried adding it in the first block, but I keep getting the error: "Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: ColXX"

Comment: player0, thank you! But I just figured it would be almost impossible to have quarterly and yearly subtotals (horizontal subtotals), so I'm afraid I'd have to go static ;( Unless you have some wonder formula in your head ;)

Comment: you mean like have daily, quarterly and yearly columns for both profit and revenue all in one formula?

Comment: yes. I'm afraid it would be too much. So basically, I need the functionality of pivot tables (subtotals), but also some features pivot tables don't provide and more responsive (collapsing pivots tables is sloooow) . It needn't be all in one formula, but I'd like it to grow horizontally with time.

Comment: should be possible I guess, if you would craft me some generic example of how exactly you wish it to look like based on some example data I believe I could manage it

Comment: Hey player0, I appreciate your helpfulness. Since I don't want to waste your time, I'll draft a more static version and present it, hoping to have the layout defined. From the formula you provided, I realized it's a bit of a challenge to modify it once it's layed out. For example, I will need somewhere between 7-10 columns per month, so I want to be really sure how much I'll really need. I'll let you know, thank you for helping.